# How to count every integer seperate integer in a list

Tags: c#

I have a list of integers(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6). I want to iterate trough this list and count every double int.

so that means I have 2 new variables

int = listcount

int = highestcount

I want to count the 1's and put the result in 'listcount'.

if listcount > highestcount

listcount = highestcount

(reset listcount)

Then check the row of '2' and do the same thing. put it in listcount and check if the count of 2 is higher than the highestcount. Is this possible without Linq?

EDIT:
I want to get the most occurring integer of the list.

```
List<int> modeList = new List<int>();

            int highestcount = 0;
            int listcount = 0;


            foreach (var item in modelist)
            {
                if (true)
                {
                    listcount > highestcount
                    listcount = highestcount;
                }

            }
```

I made some quick code for everyone to get an impression

Comment: Are you saying you want to find out which integer in a list occurs the most amount of times - the question is strangely worded?

Comment: _Is this possible without Linq?_ Sure it is.
Can you please edit your question to be more specific and show us what you tried and what your desired output is.

Comment: This question should be reopened, he asked how to do it without Linq.

Comment: @MarcoSalerno: The duplicate contains just one `Linq` answers all others are without.

Answer (score 2):

Get the number of max occurrences of a number with `LINQ` could be as:

```
var maxNumberOfOccurences= modeList.GroupBy(x => x).Select(x => x.Count()).OrderByDescending(x => x).First();
```

Without LINQ:

```
 Dictionary<int, int> occurences = new Dictionary<int, int>();
 foreach (int i in modeList)
 {
    if (occurences.ContainsKey(i))
    {
       occurences[i]++;
    }
    else
    {
       occurences.Add(i, 1);
    }
 }
 var maxNumberOfOccurences =occurences.Values.Max();
```

Comment: _Is this possible without Linq?_ - So I guess the op asks for a non `Linq` answer.

Comment: I don't want to be a nitpicker, but you should replace  `occurences.Values.Max();` with a simple for loop, since `Max()` belongs also to `System.Linq`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work:

```
   List<int> numbersList = new List<int> { 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6 };
   int previousNumber = numbersList[0];
   int countingRepetition = 0;
   int highestcount = 0;
   int theNumber = 0;

   foreach (var number in numbersList)
   {
       if (previousNumber == number)
       {
           countingRepetition++;
           if (countingRepetition >= highestcount)
           {
               highestcount = countingRepetition;
               theNumber = number;
           }
       }
       else
       {
           previousNumber = number;
           countingRepetition = 0;
       }
   }
```